# after responsive i need table header for small screen but its not working it repeated table header. because i have used for loop to print header

Tags: jquery, css, angular

I need a table header after responsive for the small screen. so, I have used media query. there are rows and after a click on each row diff-2 table will appear. because of the different table has a different header. and the header printing through a loop. but the problem is, how many headers in the first row after click .it is repeating for each row. for example for the first row, there are only three headers. and these three headers repeating for all other row so help me thank you in advance.

```
    <table class="grid-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td *ngfor="let item of items.value">
                    {{item.header}}
                </td
           </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td *ngfor="let item of items.value">
                 {{item.data}}
            </td
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table
```

My css

```
    grid-table {
    td:nth-of-type(1):before {
             content: "Groceries  (Monthly):";
          }
          td:nth-of-type(2):before {
             content: "Milk  (Monthly):";
          }
          td:nth-of-type(3):before {
             content: "Cafeteria  (Monthly):";
          }
          td:nth-of-type(4):before {
             content: "Fuel  (Monthly):";
          }
          td:nth-of-type(5):before {
              content: "Maintenance  (Annual):";
          }
          td:nth-of-type(6):before {
              content: "Local Commuting  (Monthly):";
          }

        and so on...

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I request to put the question in a proper readable way so that anyone here can assist you better. What I understood from your question is that the columns are repeating for you for all headers.

This is happening as you're repeating columns and not the rows. How *ngFor work is, it will repeat the element where you have applied it.

Possibly you could do something like this: -

```
<table class="grid-table">
    <thead>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items.value">
            <th>{{ item.header }}</th>
       </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items.value">
        <td>{{ item.data }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Also, please make sure the for is properly mentioned with uppercase 'F' as `*ngFor` and kindly use proper semantics in your HTML as well. I have used it in the code above to have it: `<th>` instead of `<td>` in the `<thead>` and closing the `<table>` tag properly.

Hope this will help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
table { 
    width: 750px; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    margin:50px auto;
    }

/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
    background: #eee; 
    }

th { 
    background: #3498db; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    }

td, th { 
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    text-align: left; 
    font-size: 18px;
    }

/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    table { 
        width: 100%; 
    }

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
    }

    td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        /* Label the data */
        content: attr(data-column);

        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
      <th>Twitter</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">James</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Matman</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@james</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Andor</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Designer</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@andornagy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Tamas</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Biro</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Game Tester</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@tamas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Zoli</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Mastah</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Developer</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@zoli</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Szabi</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@szabi</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**This makes the responsive issue solve. Next do whatever you want to add in html using angular**